# How to adapt image size for small and full screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I need to adapt image to both screen sizes (mobile and full screen)

I tried to change few things but I failed.

my div class, which have fixed width and height:

```
<div class="pull-left thumb-contenido"><img style= "max-width: 1200px; max-height: 600px;" class="center-block img-responsive img-fluid" src="{{ asset('/images/blogs/'.$post->image) }}" /></div>
```

Maybe here somehow I can set fixed image size for both screens?

Comment: Did you try using media-queries?

Comment: if you mean this: @media (max-width: 540px) , then yes

Comment: Do you mean that none of the huge amount of tutorials out there and similar questions on here helped? Also you must create a [mcve] if you need help and provide details about what didn't work.

Comment: When setting styles directly inside the HTML tag, then you have to add `!important` to your styles in your media-queries. Otherwise they won't be applied...

Answer (score -1):

With scaling images, you have two options. You can either fix one of either the width or the height and let the other adjust automatically according to the image aspect ratio. Otherwise if you need both a fixed width and height (max-width and max-height in your case) you can choose to adjust the image within the available space using the `object-fit` [property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp). Another option could be to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to adjust the resolution on different screens